# jQuery addClass() to another class

Tags: jquery, addclass

I find a class (used for a multiple td) and I would like to add at all td with this class, another class.

The class for every td is $day-momento-$x ($day is the number of today, $x can be 1, 2 or 3, because I've 3 columns).

This is my javascript code

```
var ora = new Date();
oo = ora.getHours();
giorno = ora.getDate();

//console.log('oo: '+ oo + ', giorno: ' + giorno);

        if (oo >= 4 && oo < 12) {
            $('.'+giorno+'-giornata-1').addClass('online');

        } else if (oo >= 12 && oo < 20) {
            $('.'+giorno+'-giornata-2').addClass('online');

        } else if (oo >= 20 && oo < 4) {
            $('.'+giorno+'-giornata-3').addClass('online');

        }
```

php/html code

at top I've connection with DB, and `$i` from of ajax code

```
$i = $_POST['contatore_giorni'];

    $numeroGiorno = date("j", strtotime("+".$i." days"));

    $contatore = 0;
        for ($m_p_s = 1; $m_p_s < 4; $m_p_s++) {
            $stampa_punti .= '<td class="'.$numeroGiorno.'-giornata-'.$m_p_s.'">';
        [.....]
```

Comment: nothing, I trying to stamp in console my variable  `$('.'+giorno+'-giornata-2')` and I see '25-giornata-2', In my html code exist a lot of td with this class (you can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/I3c2wmI.png )

Comment: show some html code or create `jsfiddle`.

Comment: Put your `if` conditions inside [$( document ).ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Also, your last `else if` will never be `true`. It should be just `else`, that covers it.

Comment: I use php, ajax and html, I've a connection with a localhost DB! Now I post some html and php code ahead

Comment: Thanks @ReneKorss I tryed but doesn't work with `$(document).ready ( function() { [....] });`

Comment: So the problem is that it dosen't add class? Tried it, works fine with .ready.

Comment: @ReneKorss sorry but I don't understand what you mean :( by the way, also with `$(document).ready()`, it doesn't work

Comment: I want to know what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Doesn't add the class online on all td with class `.25-giornata-3` (the right code is on top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last if says: if number is bigger than 20, but smaller than 4 (this will never happen...)

Comment: you are wrong, `giorno` is a number from 1 to 28/30/31 and `oo` is a number from 0 to 24

Comment: My bad - but still, the last if will never be true. 
Your statement says "if hours > 20 and hours <4"
A number can never be larger than 20 and smaller than 4, you should put || instead of &&, or simply remove everything after the last else ( ...}  else { ...)

Comment: Maybe you're right now, but in this moment the hour is 16 so it stay in firse else if and it doesn't work

Comment: very thanks, in my code doesn't work! Now I'm traying to find the problem :)

Comment: Do you have jQuery included? You mentioned Ajax: are you using jQuery ajax or some other framework or just plain ajax? If you are using ajax, post the code

Comment: I add the code inside of ajax success and now works! Thank you :)

Comment: I thought it was that - just one thing: you do not need the document ready part in that case, just what is inside the brackets. You are welcome